# Three.js raycaster intersection object returns strange face normals

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a model witch intersects with my raycaster. The raycaster returns the correct point, but the face normal vector is not what i'm waiting. Three.js has as built in VertexNormalsHelper, when i use that it display the correct normals, but when i create two cubes one will be at the position of the intersection point and the other will be at the normal vector it will be like this:

[image]

The **red cube** is the raycaster intersection point, **blue cube** is the face normal

My code is simple just a simple raycaster, and i copy the position of the points to the cubes. When i load my model i update everything on the geomtery. I use the Orbitcontrols for the camera movement.

```
var intersects = this.checkIntersection(this.surfaceModel);

for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {

    var p = intersects[ 0 ].point;

    var normal = intersects[ 0 ].face.normal.clone();

    //Red & Blue cube position update
    this.pointHelper_A.position.copy(p);
    this.pointHelper_B.position.copy(normal);
```

Here is an image when the VertexNormalsHelper is turned on, so you can see that the normals are fine here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned some vector math, so the normal vector is in the right position. When you need a point at the ray intersection perpendicular to the intersected face then you need to multiply the faceNormalVector with a scalar, this will be the distance between the face and the new point, and then add this new vector to the intersection point.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the source code of the VertexNormalsHelper and from that i've created a function wich gives you the normal vector of a face. So it can tell you that point but i don't think that this is the real solution for the main problem, also it has many operations.

Here is the code:

(object: *THREE.Mesh*,
face: *THREE.Face3*)

```
this.getFaceNormalPosition = function (object, face) {

    var v1 = new THREE.Vector3();

    var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

    object.updateMatrixWorld(true);

    var size = (size !== undefined) ? size : 1;

    var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3();

    normalMatrix.getNormalMatrix(object.matrixWorld);

    var vertices = new THREE.Vector3();

    var verts = object.geometry.vertices;

    var faces = object.geometry.faces;

    var worldMatrix = object.matrixWorld;


    for (var j = 0, jl = face.vertexNormals.length; j < jl; j++) {

        var vertexId = face[ keys[ j ] ];
        var vertex = verts[ vertexId ];

        var normal = face.vertexNormals[ j ];

        vertices.copy(vertex).applyMatrix4(worldMatrix);

        v1.copy(normal).applyMatrix3(normalMatrix).normalize().multiplyScalar(size);

        v1.add(vertices);
    }

    return v1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of not understanding the normal face I'm getting. The solution for me was to multiply the normal with the normal matrix of the object (didnt know that was a thing). Here is a simple helper class written in typescript, porting it to javascript shouldn't be too hard:

```
import { Vector3, Object3D, Matrix3, Face3 } from 'three';

export class Face3Utils {
    private static _matrix3: Matrix3;

    private static get matrix3(): Matrix3 {
        if(this._matrix3 === undefined) {
            this._matrix3 = new Matrix3();
        }
        return this._matrix3;
    }

    public static getWorldNormal(face: Face3, object: Object3D, normalVector?: Vector3): Vector3 {
        if(normalVector === null || normalVector === undefined) {
            normalVector = new Vector3();
        }

        object.updateMatrixWorld( true );
        Face3Utils.matrix3.getNormalMatrix( object.matrixWorld );

        normalVector.copy(face.normal).applyMatrix3( Face3Utils.matrix3 ).normalize();
        return normalVector;
    }
}
```